# How to produce such a matrix with braces in LaTeX?

Tags: matrices, braces, underbrace

Currently I am working on an assignment that needs me to typeset the following Sylvester matrix in LaTeX.

[image: sylvester matrix]

I have no idea how to typeset the two braces on the right side so I would like to ask for it. I am using the document class of amsart and I can implement any package if needed.

Thanks in advance..

ps. The enclosed is what I have so far

```
\begin{align*}
Syl_i(A,B)=
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
a_m & \cdots & a_0 & & \\
&\ddots & \cdots & \ddots & \\
& & a_m & \cdots & a_0 \\
b_n & \cdots & b_0 & & \\
&\ddots & \cdots & \ddots & \\
& &b_n & \cdots &b_0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
}_{m+n-i}
\end{align*}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to add the two braces right to the matrix..

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post what you've tried so far as MWE (minimal, but compilable code exmample).

Comment: @TeXnician Thank you! I have added details to my problem. BTW could I ask  which three words "MWE" stands for?

Comment: MWE stands for "Minimal Working Example".  The code you include should compile, even if it doesn't produce exactly the result you're expecting. Then other users can copy your code and use it as a starting point.

Comment: @SandyG Oh, I see.. And thank you for your explanation and your answer! Have a nice day~

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with some `\phantom` and `\lefteqn` commands. The idea is to stack two `\phantom` matrices to the right with the same entries as the upper and lower halves of the original. To get the `\underbrace` inside the brackets requires a matrix with no delimiters. The square brackets are added before and after with additional `\phantom` matrices.

If you want to add an additional column to the main matrix to line up the `\ddots`, everything else will adjust automatically.

[image]

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
Syl_i(A,B)=\left[\phantom{\begin{matrix}a_0\\ \ddots\\a_0\\b_0\\ \ddots\\b_0 \end{matrix}}
\right.\hspace{-1.5em}
\underbrace{\begin{matrix}
a_m & \cdots & a_0 & \\
\ddots & & \ddots & \\
 & a_m & \cdots & a_0 \\
b_n & \cdots & b_0 & \\
\ddots & & \ddots & \\
 & b_n & \cdots & b_0
\end{matrix}}_{m+n-i}
\hspace{-1.5em}
\left.\phantom{\begin{matrix}a_0\\ \ddots\\a_0\\b_0\\ \ddots\\b_0 \end{matrix}}\right]\hspace{-1em}
\begin{tabular}{l}
$\left.\lefteqn{\phantom{\begin{matrix} a_0\\ \ddots\\ a_0\ \end{matrix}}}\right\}n-i$\\
$\left.\lefteqn{\phantom{\begin{matrix} b_0\\ \ddots\\ b_0\ \end{matrix}}} \right\}m-i$
\end{tabular}
\]

\end{document}
```