# Add symbols to a given matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, matrices

I would like to add symbols and labels to a given matrix. To specify what I an looking for, I will provide some graphical examples below.

Basically, I just want to attach data to a matrix in a way that it is properly aligned. For example, We could add some keys indicating the dimensions of the matrix

[image]

Or maybe we could add some labels to the columns

[image]

In any case, I would like to know how to align certain data with data inside a given matrix.

If you would like to help, I will provide to you the code of both matrices.

```
\text{det}\begin{pmatrix} a_0 & a_1 & \dots & a_{n-1} & a_n & 0 & \dots & 0\\ 0 & a_0 & \dots & a_{n-2} & a_{n-1} & a_n & \dots & 0 \\  &  & \ddots &  &  &  & \ddots & \\ 0 & 0 & \dots & a_0 & a_1 & a_2 & \dots & a_n \\ b_0 & b_1 & \dots & b_{m-1} & b_m & 0 & \dots & 0 \\ 0 & b_0 & \dots & b_{m-2} & b_{m-1} & b_m & \dots & 0\\ & & \ddots & & & & \ddots & & \\ 0 & 0 & \dots & b_0 & b_1 & b_2 & \dots & b_m \end{pmatrix}


\text{det}\begin{pmatrix} -a & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 1 & \dots & 0\\ 0 & -a & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \dots & -a & 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & n & 0 & \dots & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & n & \dots & 0\\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & n \end{pmatrix}=(-a)^{n-1}n^n
```

Thanks in advance for your attention.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59519/134144 could be helpful for the second matrix.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40/134144 might be interesting regarding the first one.

Comment: Unrelated: NEVER use `\text{det}`, `\text` does not do what you think. Besides LaTeX already provides `\det` for that.

Comment: (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/397672/125871)

Answer (score 3):

With `nicematrix` it is rather easy and you can use the same tool to do both matrices.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}
\begin{document}
\[\det\begin{pNiceArray}{CCCCCCCC}% 
[create-medium-nodes,
code-after = {\begin{tikzpicture}[name suffix = -medium]
\draw[thick,decorate,
    decoration={calligraphic brace,amplitude=3pt,raise=1em}] 
 (1-8.north east) -- (4-8.south east) node[midway,right=1.2em]{$m$ files};
\draw[thick,decorate,
    decoration={calligraphic brace,amplitude=3pt,raise=1em}] 
 (5-8.north east) -- (8-8.south east) node[midway,right=1.2em]{$n$ files};
\end{tikzpicture}}]
 a_0 & a_1 & \Cdots & a_{n-1} & a_n & 0 & \Cdots & 0\\ 
 0 &a_0 & \Cdots & a_{n-2} & a_{n-1} & a_n & \Cdots & 0 \\ 
  &  & \Ddots &  &  &  & \Ddots & \\ 
  0 & 0 & \Cdots & a_0 & a_1 & a_2 & \Cdots & a_n \\ 
  b_0 & b_1 & \Cdots &b_{m-1} & b_m & 0 & \Cdots & 0 \\ 
  0 & b_0 & \Cdots & b_{m-2} & b_{m-1} & b_m & \Cdots & 0\\ 
  & & \Ddots & & & & \Ddots &  \\ 
  0 & 0 & \Cdots & b_0 & b_1 & b_2 & \Cdots & b_m \\
\end{pNiceArray}\]

\bigskip

\[\det\begin{pNiceArray}{CCCCCCCC}% 
[create-medium-nodes,first-row,
code-after = {\begin{tikzpicture}[name suffix = -medium]
\foreach \X in {4,5,6} {\draw[rounded corners] ([xshift=-1pt]0-\X.north west)
|- ([yshift=-1pt]0-\X.south east);}
\end{tikzpicture}}] 
 &  &   & n-1 & k & n+1 & &\\ 
-a & 0 & \Cdots & 0 & 0 & 1 & \Cdots & 0\\ 
0 & -a & \Cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & \Cdots & 0 \\ 
\Vdots & \Vdots & \Ddots & \Vdots & \Vdots & \Vdots & \Ddots & \Vdots \\ 
0 & 0 & \Cdots & -a & 0 & 0 & \Cdots & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & \Cdots & 0 & n & 0 & \Cdots & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & \Cdots & 0 & 0 & n & \Cdots & 0\\ 
\Vdots & \Vdots & \Ddots & \Vdots & \Vdots & \Vdots & \Ddots & \Vdots \\ 
0 & 0 & \Cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & \Cdots & n \end{pNiceArray}=(-a)^{n-1}n^n
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]